# toolbutton, toolbar and tooltarget (drag drop clone)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Already looked at examples like these: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/t97FE/light/ and others trying to combine several parts, but without any success.

I'm trying to implement a toolbar that creates several copies (clone) on the target using the clones which will be stored and retrieved from the database

```
<style>
.toolbutton { width: 20px; height: 20px; padding: 0px; float: left; margin: 0 2px 2px 0;text-align:center;cursor:pointer}
#tooltarget { width:200px; height:100px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 1px; }
#toolbar {width:200px;height: 22px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;border:2px solid #ccc;padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;}
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#btn_a" ).draggable({revert:'invalid',helper:"clone"});
    $( "#btn_b" ).draggable({revert:'invalid',helper:"clone"});
    $( "#btn_c" ).draggable({revert:'invalid',helper:"clone"});
    $('#tooltarget').droppable({
        accept:'.toolbutton',
        drop: function(event,ui){
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $('#tooltarget .toolbutton').addClass('target-item');
            $(".target-item").draggable({containment: 'parent'});
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="toolbar">
    <div id="btn_a" class="toolbutton ui-widget-content">A</div>
    <div id="btn_b" class="toolbutton ui-widget-content">B</div>
    <div id="btn_c" class="toolbutton ui-widget-content">C</div>
</div>

 <div id="tooltarget">
 </div>
```